# ViewGroup injection with AndroidAnnotation

Tags: android-annotations

I'm implementing an ActionBar on my Activities. I'm trying to do this as a AndroidAnnotaions @EViewGroup component, but for some reason I cannot see the component in my Activities. The project compiles fine though.

My code is basically something like below

actionbar.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/back"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/back_button"
  />

<!-- Rest of the views omitted -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

ActionBar.java

```
@EViewGroup( R.layout.actionbar )
public class ActionBar extends RelativeLayout {

private Context mContext;

public ActionBar( Context aContext, AttributeSet aAttributeSet ) {
  super( aContext );
  mContext = aContext;
}
// @Click listener methods omitted
```

And this is how I'm using it in another layout XML

```
<jandy.android.ActionBar_
  android:id="@+id/actionbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
  />
```

According to the AA documentation this is all that is required. But as said, nothing is visible.

Thanks.

Comment: make sur that @dimen/action_bar_height isn't 0 :)

Comment: @Simo thanks for the tip. No, it's not 0. And in fact I had the ActionBar as part of one layout previously. Now that I'm making the other screens, I want it as a separated and re-usable component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to implement constructors with different parameters:

```
public CustomActionbarComponent(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomActionbarComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);  
}

public CustomActionbarComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context);
}
```

Maybe the custom view created from xml use another constructor. That's the only difference with your code and my working custom actionbar.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jordifm. Unfortunately I'm not working with Android at the moment and don't have a change to give it try. If you're saying that it works as per your example, I'll trust on that and accept your answer.